# Save values generated via API as taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-taxonomy, api

I'm using the IMDB Connecter plugin to grab meta data for movies and I'm wondering if I can save some of the information it generates as terms in a custom taxonomy that already exists.

What I want to do is to be able to save the "Director" and "Actors" information generated by the plugin as taxonomy terms. So for example, the values in the array generated by the `$actors` function would be saved as individual terms in my custom taxonomy `actors`.

This is my current code.

```
$imdb = get_field('imdb_id'); // IMDB movie ID is saved as a custom meta value
$imdbInfo = get_imdb_connector_movie($imdb);
$actors = $imdbInfo['actors']; // Gets an array of actor names
$director = $imdbInfo['director']; // Gets an array of directors
```

Is it possible to save these values as custom terms?

Comment: I'm guessing [`wp_insert_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as easy as:

```
function wpse_199523_save_imdb_terms( $post_id ) {
    if ( ! $imdb = get_field( 'imdb_id', $post_id ) )
        return;
    if ( ! $data = imdb_connector_get_movie( $imdb ) )
        return;

    if ( ! empty( $data['actors'] ) )
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $data['actors'], 'actors' );
    if ( ! empty( $data['director'] ) )
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $data['director'], 'directors' );
}

add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse_199523_save_imdb_terms', 500 /* Ensure we run after ACF */ );
```

Refer to the codex on [`wp_set_object_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms)

Comment: This didn't work for me. It didn't create the new taxonomy terms

Comment: Typo, see edited answer.

Comment: still nothing. I tried it like this and also by changing `get_imdb_connector_movie` to `imdb_connector_get_movie` like it is in the plugin and neither worked.

Comment: Make sure you have `WP_DEBUG` defined as `true` in your `wp-config.php`, add `exit;` inside the end of the function, then re-save the post and see what errors (if any) you get.

Comment: nothing came up. No errors.

Comment: Did you get just a white screen?

Comment: No. The page loaded fine, but no new terms were created when I saved a post that should have created a new `director` term based on the IMDB ID I passed to it

Comment: Make sure you add `exit;` at the end of (inside) the function - otherwise WordPress will redirect on save and you'll never see the errors - you should get a white screen if everything is ok.

Comment: it is inside the function, and it just saves the post as normal. Does that mean there's an error?

Comment: Use [this debug snippet](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bab0014a0433256db8ae) and let me know what you get.

Comment: I get [https://gist.github.com/poisontonomes/2692a245ab11e3f2b8a6] this message. Note : I've edited out my local installation path

Comment: LOL. The developer hasn't done a great job at deprecation. Old functions should still *function* until they're completely removed. Plus the deprecation notice is wrong! Long story short, use `imdb_connector_get_movie` instead of `get_imdb_connector_movie` in the debug script and see what you get this time.

Comment: ok so changing that to `imdb_connector_get_movie` in your debug snippet worked and it outputs a load of information about the IMDB listing. So to get this working should I just change `get_imdb_connector_movie` to `imdb_connector_get_movie` in your original answer?